# How to automatically select a dropdown value by passing dropdown value's id?

Tags: angular, angular10

I want automatically selected job name in dropdown according previously selected job. In order to that i pass that selected job id in  next page

[image: you can see this in this image]

And now that Dropdown containing all jobs
[image: check this]

html

```
                       <div class="col-md-6 ">
                            <div class="form-c rfcol">

                                <select id="jobData" name="jobTitle" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup"
                                    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Select name of the post applying for">
                                    <option  disabled selected value="Select">Select name of the post applying for</option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let item of jobData" [ngValue]="item">{{item.jobTitle}}</option>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gotoTop();
    this.careerJobid = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.backendService.getjobs().subscribe(jobData => {
      this.jobData = jobData;

      console.log("Job List")
      console.log(this.jobData)

    });

  }
```

where careerJobid stores the passed id

Answer (score 0):

`selectedGroup` is your property that is bound in the HTML. So in order to properly have the previously selected one selected, in your `.ts` file set

```
this.selectedGroup = this.careerJobid
```

in your `ngOnInit` after you set `this.careerJobid`

Comment: sorry dear it's not worked. Before doing this i just try to display a messege in dropdown (ie , <option  disabled selected value="Select">Select name of the post applying for</option>) unfortunately that's not worked. This may be the reason why your code work failed